# Using SQL query in a VS2022 ASP.NET Core 7 program

Tags: visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-7.0

I don't want to do scaffolding because the database has too many elements. I only want to access a few using a SQL query.

So

1. Do I set my `{ get; set; }` to only those items I want and then manually create a screen to display them. OR
2. Would it be better to do a `select *` and put the entire database into a grid display?

Option #1 should be easy but in Option #2, I don't know how to create a grid display.

Doing the scaffolding method does not work in what I want to do.